# Run SQLite statement in Database Inspector Button not showing in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

If app uses **Room**, Android Studio provides **gutter actions** that allow to quickly run query methods that have already defined in **DAO** classes as the [Android studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database#dao-queries) . So my expection was to get the gutter action like the below image.

**Expectation**

[image: Expectation]

But I'm not getting the gutter action called  **Run SQLite statement in Database Inspector** in my case. My DAO's image is attached below -

**Reality**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually storing my **table** and **column** name in Java's `public static final String` field as  **constant** and using it room query. So I just simple removed the constant and add the **original/direct** name of **table** and **column** name then it was showing the button finally.

[image]